# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError with return redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError` in this method, specifically in the `return redirect_to controller_action_path` line.

Can't understand why is this happening since I'm using `return` before the `redirect_to` and that would supposedly end execution there.

```
  def update
    if current_user.update_attributes(profile_attributes)
      if verification?
        send_user_email
      end
      return redirect_to controller_action_path
    end
  end
```

Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any `before_filter` s which may be rendering?

Comment: Yes, a [Sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) `before_filter :require_login`.

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_to` is also a render. If you don't want to redirect just write return. And if you want to redirect, you need to remove the other render you have in place.

Comment: I can't think of any other reason why this would happen. Did you try to hit your action without the `redirect_to` and see if it gives any error like template missing ?